# USB icon (system tray) not working

Tags: windows, usb, eject

I have an issue, my USB system tray icon stops working after ejecting a drive; so, after successfully ejecting a disk, does no longer responds to any click, right-click, double-click, does not matter. Is "dead". Is happening in a lot of cases, some 70-80 % of occasions.

I did not found a correlation with a particular disk drive, drive ejecting order, I even have now a second laptop and found the issue repeating on this one too.

Laptops are both Asus, but different models; and more than 6 years between models. So it is probably not a driver issue.
I have Windows 10, on first laptop is version 1709 (or 1907..?) and on the second one is a windows10 from 2022
Is there a bug in the OS?
If yes, does somebody found a patch to Win? Not USB ejecting third-party programs, I already use one but is not what I want...

Comment: You should first try to update to Windows 10 22H2. Press Win + i then go to updates. Sometimes you have to trigger the update manually. Press Win + r  then enter *winver* to see your Windows version.

Comment: Test when booting in Safe mode, to see if this is caused by an installed product.

Comment: On some PC's, I've found *Safely eject...* unreliable, and use third-party tools, such as free *HotSwap!* , http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm , or one of the many alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/hotswap/

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to `Device Setup Manager` service malfunction since this service provides Safely Remove Hardware (IIRC nothing happens when pressing on icon if the service was off on system startup).

Try setting it to Manual and restarting the service (via GUI or via `net restart dsmsvc` command from Command Prompt) when you encounter the problem. Type Services from Start Menu to get to GUI control panel.

You can also use this BAT (or execute line from Command Prompt) to call Safely Remove Hardware dialog while looking for a proper fix:

```
RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for answers, I will try both and let you know if got some success.